# Correct way to get a value from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb and mysql with my nodejs.

```
employee.find({status:1}, function(error,response) {
                for(i=0;i<=response.length;i++){
                  var fileid = response[i]._id;
                  var sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE `id` = '"+fileid+"'";
                  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Result: " + result);
  });
                  }
                })
```

The above code gives me the exact record and result but in my logger file i am getting the below error everytime,But i have no problem in getting my output.I am using winston to record my service logs. The main reason why i am worrying about this error is my node js APi's are going down more or less after every 8 hours and my databases are not going idle(using forever npm module to run my service forever) and so i am believing that this might be the reason for killing my node processess. Below is my error.Any help?

```
"stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"(var fileid = response[i]._id;)]
```

Comment: what result you get in `response[i]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `i` should be less than `response.length`. array length is always greater than the last index.
 For example,

```
var arr = [1,2]; //length is 2 and last index value is 1
```

Change you code like this:  `for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)`

```
 employee.find({status:1}, function(error,response) {
                    for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                      var fileid = response[i]._id;
                      var sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE `id` = '"+fileid+"'";
                      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                         if (err) throw err;
                           console.log("Result: " + result);
                        });
                      }
                    })
```

Comment: bug fixed ....any possibility ? will it be a reason for my webservices are getting killed after certain period?

Comment: Yes. your server will crash as error handling is not done.

Comment: if all these errors are fixed on one time running forever process whether my service will run life long?

Comment: it should. Also I will recommend exception handling. You can use `try` `catch` for same.